# error loading jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I just updated my jquery and jquery-ui. Here is what I added:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>     
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fastLiveFilter.js"></script>  
<script src="js/class.js"></script>
<link href="js/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  
<link href='css/common.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

But the datepicker is not working. If I add the following script:

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.2/external/jquery/jquery-ui.css"></script>
```

the I get the error-  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Here is the jquery code:

```
 //add date selector
    $("#datediv").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd M yy"
     });

     $("#datediv").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: Is there any other console error ? whether jquery and jquery ui loaded properly ?

Comment: <input id = 'date' name = 'date' size = '20' class='datediv'>. All scripts loaded properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your id for input is date not datediv so you can write like this 
or else you can write `$(".datediv")` instead of `$("#date")` if you want to pass it by class name

```
$(document).ready(function($){

    $("#date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd M yy"
    });

    $("#date").datepicker("setDate", new Date());

});
```

Comment: Yes, thats how it is...I just didnt mention the document.ready part

Comment: ok problem is that jquery not finding element having id datediv because its class name, and your id is date

Answer (score 1):

Why do you add a style sheet using `<script>` tag instead of a `<link>` tag?

Try using this

```
<link href="js/jquery-ui-1.11.2/external/jquery/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```